# Limit login attempts?

Tags: java

I am trying to limit the login attempts for a password program to 3 but when I use the while loop it asks for the password 3 times even when it is entered correctly on the first try. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Password {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

   String password, input;
   int maxAttempts;

   password = "Joe";
   maxAttempts = 0;

   while(maxAttempts < 3)
   {

   System.out.print("Enter your password: ");
   input = keyboard.nextLine();

   if(input.equals(password)) 

    System.out.println("Congratulations");

   else

    System.out.println("Incorrect. Try Again.");

    maxAttempts++;
   }

   }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend using `{` and `}` characters for EVERY branch or loop.  That is, whenever you write `if`, `else`, `for`, `while` or `do`, put a `{` afterwards, just to make it clear what the scope of the branch or loop is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exit from the while loop by placing a break; statement.

In your program change the following

```
  if(input.equals(password)) 
      System.out.println("Congratulations");
```

To

```
  if(input.equals(password)) 
  {
      System.out.println("Congratulations");
      break;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no break what is said above. The while.only wants know if the attemps are more than 3 does not care if the password is correct.